# Do i have to compile a PHP extension on Windows to use it with Windows?

Tags: php, windows, dll, compilation, php-extension

I'm trying to compile a "hello world" type extension on Windows 7, but I'm running into all kinds of problems. My end goal is to use the compiled extension with PHP (using wampserver2).

**It it possible to compile the extension on Linux and still have it work on Windows?**

I noticed all extensions in the ext folder in WAMP/PHP are `.dll`.  Is there a way to produce a DLL for Windows on a linux machine, or do I have to compile on Windows too?

Comment: It'd be possible to cross-compile, but then you'd need to have basically a windows dev. environment on the linux system (e.g. Wine) for the compiler to work with. The effort involved in getting that working to the point where the resulting .dlls work on a REAL windows system is most likely not worth it.

Comment: @Marc B, so basically if someone has an extension that they want to have run on both linux and windows (for wampserver and the like), they have to compile twice, one on Windows and once on Linux. Did I get that right? I mean, I can't just take the linux compilation and somehow have it also work on windows out of the box. Right?

Comment: Yeah, two different compiles. The linux compile would be using libc functions and whatnot, the windows one would be using Win32 or whatever. It's not a simple matter of renaming the .so file to .dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be possible to cross-compile, but then you'd need to have basically a windows development environment on the linux system (e.g. Wine) for the compiler to work with. The effort involved in getting that working to the point where the resulting .dlls work on a REAL windows system is most likely not worth it.